Paper suggestions on innovation-economics
I am in search of seminal theoretical papers in innovation economics, with a particular interest in recent works that model innovation processes. Ideally, I'm looking for papers that explore the "production" of innovation (or how ideas are generated by workers), or examine the effects of certain policies on the distribution of innovation. Although I have conducted searches on Google Scholar, I haven't quite found what I am seeking. To provide clarity on the type of research I'm interested in, below is a list of some papers I've encountered; however, these don't fully meet my criteria:

Innovation, Reallocation, and Growth (Acemoglu et al., 2017)
ARE IDEAS GETTING HARDER TO FIND? (Bloom et al., 2017)
"Innovation and Trade Policy in a Globalized World" by Ufuk Akcigit, Sina T. Ates, and Giammario Impullitti.
rowth Through Heterogeneous Innovations" by Ufuk Akcigit and William R. Kerr.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

I believe the old "learning-by-doing" models can be also interpreted as worker driven innovation, although it is broader concept.
Here is a reference for modern version of the model (learning by doing is one of the oldest growth models);
Thompson, Peter. "Learning by doing." Handbook of the Economics of Innovation 1 (2010): 429-476.
